# Object required but can't find where it is missing

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I'm trying to get this vba code to run but I am getting an "object required" error. When I debug, nothing is highlighted. I am not seeing where the object missing because of this. I'm running Excel 2010. Thanks, in advance, for any help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim Yr, Yr_P
    Dim Qinput As String
    Dim Sheet6, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 As Object

'get new year
    Qinput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the year you want to create data for")
      If Qinput = vbNullString Then
      Exit Sub
      Else
      End If

'identify year
    Yr = Right(Left(Qinput, 4), 2)
    Yr_P = Yr - 1

'change new on tabnames
    Sheet6.Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (AMSG) Total"
    Sheet1.Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(US)"
    Sheet2.Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(MCU)"
    Sheet3.Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (PDSN)"

'update headers
    With Sheet6
        Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
        Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

        Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
        Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
        Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
        Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
        Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
        Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

        Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
        Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
        Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
        Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
        Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
        Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
        Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
        Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
        Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
        Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
        Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
        Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
        Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr

    End With

    With Sheet1
        Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
        Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

        Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
        Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
        Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
        Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
        Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
        Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

        Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
        Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
        Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
        Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
        Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
        Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
        Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
        Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
        Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
        Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
        Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
        Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
        Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr

'copy all Q4 data from columns AM-AO and paste into C-E the delete/clear the old data
       Sheet1.Cells("AM4:AO13").Value = Sheet1.Cells("C4:E13").Value
       Sheet1.Cells("AM4:AO13").ClearContents
       Sheet1.Cells("AM18:AO32").Value = Sheet1("C18:E32").Value
       Sheet1.Cells("AM18:AO32").ClearContents
       Sheet1.Cells("AM44:AO47").Value = Sheet1.Cells("C44:E47").Value
       Sheet1.Cells("AM44:AO47").ClearContents
       Sheet1.Cells("AS50").Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Cells("H50")
       Sheet1.Cells("AS50,Q50,Z50,AI50,AX50").ClearContents



    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Yr, Yr_P` has nothing after it. That might be a place to start looking.

Comment: I should have added, the code for Sheet6 works but hangs up on the code for Sheet1. Andrew, the Dim has worked. What would you recommed setting it as? Would that be a String?

Comment: If it's a year, probably an int.

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem but it looks like this is a typo will give you some wonky results.            

Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"

Comment: The year update works on Sheet6 headings and all of the TabNames, so I don't think that is the issue. The problem is the year code doesn't do anything on the other 3 sheets which is why I'm forced to hand/hard code each of the following sheets. Plus, the second half of the code on sheet1 will only be on Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3. I've tried arrays, cases and every incarnation to get this code to wrok the way I want it to but no luck (I managed to get it to work on only the last page but it causes problems on the first sheet)

Comment: Try stepping through the code with F8 and see where it fails

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I made the code for sheet6 a comment and it is still throwing the error. I also updated the Yr line to an integer as yoou suggested.

Comment: F8 showed the object required on Sheet6. Sheet6 is an object. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Information on [How to use Sheets by Index Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221564(v=office.11).aspx)

Use `Worksheets(6)` instead of `sheet6`

You have declared `Dim Sheet6, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 As Object` but Application has no idea of whether they mean `Sheets` in the workbook or something else

Remove the declaration and change all references to sheets as `Worksheets(Index-No)`

For e.g. `With Sheet1` will become `With Worksheets(1)`  etc

P.S Make sure you have 6 sheets in your workbook created

### Complete Solution:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim Yr, Yr_P
    Dim Qinput As String   
'get new year
    Qinput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the year you want to create data for")
      If Qinput = vbNullString Then
      Exit Sub
      Else
      End If

'identify year
    Yr = Right(Left(Qinput, 4), 2)
    Yr_P = Yr - 1

'change new on tabnames
    Worksheets(6).Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (AMSG) Total"
    Worksheets(1).Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(US)"
    Worksheets(2).Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(MCU)"
    Worksheets(3).Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (PDSN)"

'update headers
    With Worksheets(6)
        Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
        Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

        Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
        Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
        Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
        Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
        Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
        Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

        Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
        Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
        Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
        Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
        Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
        Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
        Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
        Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
        Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
        Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
        Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
        Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
        Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr

    End With

    With Worksheets(1)
        Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
        Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
        Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

        Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
        Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
        Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
        Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
        Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
        Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
        Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

        Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
        Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
        Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
        Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
        Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
        Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
        Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
        Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
        Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
        Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
        Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
        Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
        Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
        Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr

'copy all Q4 data from columns AM-AO and paste into C-E the delete/clear the old data
       Worksheets(1).Range("C4:E13").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("AM4:AO13")
       Worksheets(1).Range("AM4:AO13").ClearContents
       Worksheets(1).Range("C18:E32").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("AM18:AO32").Value
       Worksheets(1).Range("AM18:AO32").ClearContents
       Worksheets(1).Range("C44:E47").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("AM44:AO47").Value
       Worksheets(1).Range("AM44:AO47").ClearContents
       Worksheets(1).Range("AS50").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("H50")
       Worksheets(1).Range("AS50,Q50,Z50,AI50,AX50").ClearContents  

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I change Sheets to worksheets but now, I'm getting an "object variable or with block variable not set" error. I know this has got to be something simple but I am just not seeing it (still a beginner as you can tell). Do I need to add Set Worksheets= something?

Comment: First off, thank you everyone for your help. I had a family emergency and had to fly out of the office.

Comment: Thinkingcap, this gives me an error on the destination copy for cell "AS50" (second to last line) but I think I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (AMSG) Total"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(US)"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(MCU)"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Name= "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (PDSN)"
```

Solves some of the problem.  There is still an issue with the bottom block of code.

Edit: Thinking cap reminded me that I did Dim Sheet6, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 As worksheet

Edit 2:     This is not switching sheets properly, change...

Edit 3:

I have tested it.  The December typo commented on in the question still exists and still gives a wonky output but the following code succeeds up to the copy portion.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim sh As Object
Dim Yr As Integer
Dim Yr_P As Integer
Dim Qinput As String
Dim Sheet6, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3  As Worksheet






'get new year
 Qinput = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the year you want to create data for")
  If Qinput = vbNullString Then
  Exit Sub
  Else
  End If

'identify year
Yr = Right(Left(Qinput, 4), 2)
Yr_P = Yr - 1



'change new on tabnames
Worksheets("Sheet6").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (AMSG) Total"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(US)"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(MCU)"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Name = "FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (PDSN)"

'update headers
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast (AMSG) Total").Activate
    Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
    Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

    Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
    Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
    Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
    Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
    Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
    Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
    Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
    Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

    Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
    Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
    Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
    Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
    Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
    Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
    Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
    Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
    Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
    Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
    Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
    Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
    Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
    Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
    Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr



 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FY" & Yr & "GM Forecast(US)").Activate
    Cells(1, 6) = "FY" & Yr_P
    Cells(1, 15) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 24) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 33) = "FY" & Yr
    Cells(1, 42) = "FY" & Yr

    Cells(2, 3) = "FY" & Yr_P & "Q4"
    Cells(2, 12) = "FY" & Yr & "Q1"
    Cells(2, 21) = "FY" & Yr & "Q2"
    Cells(2, 30) = "FY" & Yr & "Q3"
    Cells(2, 39) = "FY" & Yr & "Q4"
    Cells(2, 48) = "FY" & Yr & "(to date)"
    Cells(2, 49) = "FY" & Yr & "FCST"
    Cells(2, 51) = "Normalized FY" & Yr & "FCST"

    Cells(3, 3) = "Jul," & Yr_P
    Cells(3, 4) = "Aug," & Yr_P
    Cells(3, 5) = "Sep," & Yr
    Cells(3, 12) = "Oct," & Yr
    Cells(3, 13) = "Nov," & Yr
    Cells(3, 14) = "Dec,) & Yr"
    Cells(3, 21) = "Jan," & Yr
    Cells(3, 22) = "Feb," & Yr
    Cells(3, 23) = "Mar," & Yr
    Cells(3, 30) = "Apr," & Yr
    Cells(3, 31) = "May," & Yr
    Cells(3, 32) = "Jun," & Yr
    Cells(3, 39) = "Jul," & Yr
    Cells(3, 40) = "Aug," & Yr
    Cells(3, 41) = "Sep," & Yr

'copy all Q4 data from columns AM-AO and paste into C-E the delete/clear the old data
   Sheet1.Cells("AM4:AO13").Value = Sheet1.Cells("C4:E13").Value
   Sheet1.Cells("AM4:AO13").ClearContents
   Sheet1.Cells("AM18:AO32").Value = Sheet1("C18:E32").Value
   Sheet1.Cells("AM18:AO32").ClearContents
   Sheet1.Cells("AM44:AO47").Value = Sheet1.Cells("C44:E47").Value
   Sheet1.Cells("AM44:AO47").ClearContents
   Sheet1.Cells("AS50").Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Cells("H50")
   Sheet1.Cells("AS50,Q50,Z50,AI50,AX50").ClearContents





End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried both of these suggestions and neither have worked. There are actually 8 sheets in the workbook but only these 4 need to be changed. The order (6 first, instead of 1) is due to the way the template was originally set up and then arranged. I'm not sure if the order was causing a problem.

Comment: Are the sheet names presently "sheet1","sheet2","sheet3", etc.  because this will fail if they are not.

Comment: Also for the bottom portion of the code at least a part of the problem is this "Sheet1.Cells("AM4:AO13")" is not how you define cells.  Back to work now.  Best of luck with this.

Comment: Myles, your suggestion still gave me a subscript out of range error on Sheet6. I really appreciate your help. With everyone's input I think I can get this to work now! :-) (Yeah, huzzah, there was much celebrating)

Comment: Okay. I'm still fighting with the same error, despite changes. I've tried making the sheets as worksheet and as object. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit your question, adding the most up to date code at the bottom?  Also please confirm that your sheet names are presently sheet1,sheet2,sheet3, and sheet6 as variation in the sheet name will cause failure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to refer to a worksheet object:

- by passing its index - ie the number representing the sheet order in the sheets tab - or name to the worksheets method

  ```
  worksheets(index)
  worksheets("Name")
  ```
- by its code name

  ```
  codeName
  ```

Make sure not to get mixed up

Comment: To Myles and IAmDreanged- I am trying to use the code names as the tabnames change and I don't want to hardcode anything to them

Comment: What are "Code names?"

Comment: In the left hand window in the macro, under the project tab, there is a listing of what is involved in the macro. The sheets are coded there with the tabname in parenthesis next to it

Comment: Well if these are code names you are using, don't declare them as variables. This actually looks to override your calling the worksheets with their code name with third party objects